# Which model to use for word tokenization?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language, artificial-intelligence

What type of model for word tokenization in a group of words is good?? I want to tokenize skills in a group. There are multiple groups, and I want to predict group number using a single skill.

I have used BERT but I think it's mainly used for sentences not list of words.

Can you suggest better model??